# C# application doesn't create file if called from command prompt

Tags: c#, command, exec, prompt, shell-exec

I have a simple C# console application which writes some information to a text file. The application works fine when opened from desktop (by clicking on the .exe file). However when I open the application via command prompt, the console window will open normally but the application won't write anything to the text file (the other code functions work normally in the console window).

Fyi I need to open the application via command prompt because later on the exe application will be put on server and called from a php script (using exec or shell_exec).

I assume this might be an issue with write permissions or something, but no error is thrown at any point so I'm not sure. Any ideas please?

My code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string arg="";
        try
        {
            arg = args[0];
        }
        catch { 
        }
        using (StreamWriter outputWriter = File.AppendText(@"C:\Archive\test.txt"))
        {
            outputWriter.WriteLine("arg="+arg);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like permission issues. for the command prompt have your tried running it as administrator, to see if that works? Also ensure you are in the correct directory

Comment: Yes, I tried running command prompt as admin but got the same result. Also the current directory in cmd should not be an issue, since I hard coded the path to the text file.

Comment: Can you also edit the question with the output ?  (I'm curious as to whether `Test` is printed out.

Answer (score 1):

when you run your application from the commandline, the current directory depends on your location in the prompt.

when running your .exe make sure you run it from the same directory as the file you want to write to.

If this solves the problem, then you'll need to write code to handle the case where the file to write to is not in the current directory, perhaps set it by code.

Comment: I thought of that too, and tried hard coding the full path to the txt file in my C# code. So when the exe file is started from the command prompt (regardless of which directory I'm currently in) the exe should just write to the specified txt file. But it doesn't.

Comment: Sure, it's just a simple code I used for test purposes:        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string arg="";
            try
            {
                arg = args[0];
            }
            catch { 
            }
            using (StreamWriter outputWriter = File.AppendText(@"C:\Archive\test.txt"))
            {
                outputWriter.WriteLine("arg="+arg);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

Comment: sorry about the compressed text, couldn't find how to copy the code properly yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what happened, but I'm trying again now via command prompt and the code works as expected. It could be that I removed any hidden errors as I cleaned up the code to post it here. Ugh.. :-)